# Does Quartus support in-memory synthesis?

Tags: quartus, intel-fpga

I'm working on a project that generates a large number of components. I'm having the problem that Quartus is generating an extremely large number of files in the /db directory, on the order of hundreds of thousands.

The system I am working on has limited storage that is also very slow. Just deleting the db folder is taking over 20mins, and for the project I have to do many separate builds, so it's a significant bottle neck.

Does Quartus support keeping the db archive in ram during synthesis?

Vivado has the `-in-memory` option for the `create_project` command. Is there a Quartus equivalent? I've look through the "Quartus II Scripting reference manual" and found nothing yet.

Quartus version is 19.1

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not able to find any option similar to -in-memory.

However, I'm working on a linux system, so by placing the build directory in tmpfs (ram file system) I was able to get a *significant* improvement in performance.